What is the correct way to implement a custom std::formatter in C++20?
I've looked at several articles on custom formatters for the C++20 formatting library, but many seem subtly incorrect or fail to compile on my toolchain. Below is an example I believe is correct followed by 3 specific questions.
#include <print>

struct CustomType {
    int a;
};

template<>
struct std::formatter<CustomType> : std::formatter<int> {

    // use format specifiers for int
    using std::formatter<int>::parse;

    auto format(CustomType const& x, auto & ctx) const {
        auto out = ctx.out();
        out = std::format_to(out, "[");

        ctx.advance_to(out);
        out = std::formatter<int>::format(x.a, ctx);

        return std::format_to(out, "]");
    }
};

int main() {
    std::println("{:>2}", CustomType{1});
    return 0;
}

Are these statements correct?

The format method should be templated on the format context type instead of using std::format_context, as many online examples suggest.
The format method should be const qualified.
The output iterator needs to be manually updated when using format_to(). Most examples omit this and seem to assume a std::back_insert_iterator, but as far as I can tell the standard does not mandate that even for std::format_context.


There are built-in range formatters, you shouldn't write your own.

Thanks. The question was intended more generically though. How to properly implement a formatter. Using it for a range was just an example.

may be https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place?

Before you post at [codereview.se], be sure to read A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code is for, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Happy to try to post to codereview if that's a better place to get answers. Note that the purpose was not really a code review, but rather a more generic question on what the right way to use a custom std::formatter is when many sources including text books seem incorrect (breaking a subset of 1-3). I updated the code sample to be more illustrative.

I believe using std::formatter<int>::parse; is redundant.  Member functions in a base class are already visible unless you take measures to prevent it.

Yes, using std::formatter::parse is redundant in this case. I added it mostly for documentation purposes as it might not be obvious otherwise that the parse method is delegated.


The format method should be templated on the format context type instead of using std::format_context, as many online examples suggest.

Yes.

The format method should be const qualified.

Yes.

The output iterator needs to be manually updated when using format_to(). Most examples omit this and seem to assume a std::back_insert_iterator, but as far as I can tell the standard does not mandate that even for std::format_context.

Yes. While the library tends to use the same, one iterator type for all char types, this isn't the only thing you can do - and if format is ever instantiated with a context that has an iterator type for which position is important - like, say, char* - then if you don't advance_to, your next format will overwrite your first one (e.g. the FMT_COMPILE approach in {fmt} doesn't wrap the iterator, so you can create a situation where the output iterator is char* and then this happens).
For this reason it might be less error prone to:
ctx.advance_to(std::format_to(ctx.out(), "["));
ctx.advance_to(std::formatter<int>::format(x.a, ctx));
return std::format_to(ctx.out(), "]");

Although that's admittedly more tedious. It'd be nice if there was better library support for this sort of thing, but I'm not sure what that would look like.

Thanks, this was very helpful! The last point feels like a pretty big design flaw. I.e. that the most straightforward approach will appear to work for the most common use cases but is silently wrong for more obscure cases. I agree that your proposed change is less error prone and probably the right path to take, but most people won't know that. It would maybe have been better if there was a way to rely on the output iterator having back_inserter-like behavior even if that meant that raw buffers needed an adaptor type...
